# What is the name of the editing technique by which foreground objects are set in motion?

Tags: animation

One well known example of this technique is the GTA load screen.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_YJnor4XH4

Also, I would appreciate it if you could direct me to a good tutorial video as well as the ideal software to use. Thanks!

Comment: The technique you're looking for is likely called parallax but we can't tell because you don't describe it well. Also, for help with implementation you need to include what you've tried and any resources you looked at

Comment: This isn't really an _editing_ technique, it's more of an animation technique.  I assume you mean the logos moving from right to left?  You would simply keyframe whatever animations you would like, for them to move across the screen.  If you're asking how to _layer_ objects then you stack them in your timeline accordingly.  It's pretty unclear what you're even asking about here...

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're looking for is **Cinemagraph**. Check out this [course](http://goo.gl/501d4z) on Lynda.com

Comment: I don't think that's what they were referring to.  They didn't give much info, in their question, but I'm assuming they want to know how to animate the logos in the foreground, over the background.  Cinemagraph is something completely different.